# How do I restrict typing data into a date field to only certain charaters?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, input, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a Rails 5 app.  I have a coffee script file in which I'd like to create a function that restricts someone entering a date object by typing in data.  I would like the form to be like

```
12/31/2017
```

but i would like the person to only be able to enter numbers (and move the cursor around with the arrow keys).  I would like the slashes to be automatically added.  I tried creating this

```
add_slahes_to_date = (input) ->
  if input.value != input.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')
  v = input.value
  if v.match(/^\d{2}$/)
    input.value = v + '/'
  else if v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/)
    input.value = v + '/'
```

but it has several problems.  It will automatically add a slash, but on the next entry it will remove the slash.  Also when the slash is added, I'm not able to hit the left arrow to go back and edit the numbers before the first slash.

What's the right way to restrict date entry to just numbers but have the slashes auto-added?  I'm using jQuery too if taht helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two things here...

1. Restrict the field character to numbers
2. The slashes auto add

And I would add a date validation... Since `55/66/9999` is obviously not a valid date.

So to validate a date, I suggest the use of [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

I also added a year limitation (between 1980 and 2050 in the example).

Then... The user has to be able to correct a mistake, so the backspace key, delete key and left/right arrows are allowed.

```js
$('.date')
  .on("keydown",function(e){
  //console.log(e.which);
  
  // Remove error background-color
  $(this).css({"background-color":"initial"});

  // Diallow character that are not a numbers 0 to 9 (both keypads), but allow backspace and left/right arrows
  if( (e.which<48 || e.which>57) && (e.which<96 || e.which>105) && e.which!=8 && e.which!=46 && e.which!=37 && e.which!=39){
    return false;
  }
  
}).on("keyup",function(e){
  if(e.which!=8 && e.which!=46 && e.which!=37 && e.which!=39){
    var value = $(this).val();

    // Auto add slashes
    pattern = /(\d{1,2})?(\/)?(\d{1,2})/g;
    var match = value.match(pattern);
    //console.log(match);

    if( (value.length==2 || value.length==5) && typeof(match)!="null" ){
      $(this).val(match+"/");
    }

    // When all digits are entered
    if( value.length==10 ){


      var date = value.split("/");
      var valid;
      if( (parseInt(date[2])>=1980) && (parseInt(date[2])<=2050) ){

        // Use Moment to validate the date. Will return "invalid date" on impossible dates
        valid = moment(date[2]+"-"+date[0]+"-"+date[1]).format("MM/DD/Y");

      }else{
        valid = "Invalid date";
      }

      // Show error color to user
      if(valid=="Invalid date"){
        $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
      }else{
        $(this).css({"background-color":"green"}).trigger("blur");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input class="date" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY"></input>
```

Comment: Hi, This is working great except for the fact that when I enter something like "01/01/" and then want to correct the second "01" to be "02" by hitting backspace, I can't edit things.  If I use the arrows and manually replace the second "1" by hitting backspace (or "delete"), it then gets replaced to be "01/0//".  Any way to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to detect when the the date was entered and the replace function to replace the value with the capturing groups separated by /.

```js
$('#date').on("input",function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '').replace(/(\d{2})\/?(\d{2})\/?(\d{4})/,'$1/$2/$3'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date"></input>
```

If you want to insert them after each segment you can use the following:

```js
$('#date').on("input",function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/, ''))
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{2})$/,'$1/'))
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{2})\/?(\d{2})$/,'$1/$2/'))
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{2})\/?(\d{2})\/?(\d{4})$/,'$1/$2/$3'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date"></input>
```